# Creating an app with apache cordova, always show Android target: not installed

Tags: cordova

and this problem shows,,,, Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/AvdManagerCli has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

someone can help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.